# Could not compile SwiftScript source: line 1:1: unexpected token: println

Tags: swift

I am learning Swift, and have downloaded the latest stable version (0.94.1) to a Linux machine and am trying to write some pure Swift code, and compiling it. So I have everything setup, and the examples from the examples folder work, and produce a file that says "Hellow, World!". But I want this to appear on the screen, just like `println` in the iOS documentation. So I have written a file which has one line `println("Hello, World!")` and tried to run it, but the output was `Could not compile SwiftScript source: line 1:1: unexpected token: println`.

Can someone post here a working hello world program?

Comment: The "Swift parallel scripting language " is completely unrelated to Apple's Swift programming language. The latter is, as far as I know, only available for OS X and iOS devices, but not for Linux.

Comment: I know that, yet, I have no idea how to print something. All tutorials assume you are working with Xcode...

Comment: There is no Swift compiler for Linux.

Comment: As I said in the question, I already have one working. But it is outputting files not printing to the screen. See [this](http://swift-lang.org/downloads/index.php)

Comment: To take a step back here, which programming language are you expecting that compiler to compile? Apple's [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), or the completely different [Swift](http://swift-lang.org/main/)? Because your question is tagged for Apple's Swift, and `println` is a function from Apple's Swift, but you appear to have downloaded [The Swift Parallel Scripting Language](http://swift-lang.org/main/) compiler, which has nothing whatever to do with iOS or Apple.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused entirely by confusion between two different programming languages, but is not actually a question *about* that confusion.

Comment: No idea what a "completely different swift" is. But as far as I know there is the swift language and Apples framework with Cocoa and all. I want plain simple swift, no UI. Just a simple file where I can try stuff out like making classes, sub-classes, find other tweaks of the swift language.

Comment: Then you have (a) downloaded the wrong compiler, for an earlier, completely separate language, made by a different organisation, and (b) are using the wrong operating system. As far as I know, Apple's Swift can only be compiled on OS X. I'll take another run at explaining this, in different words: There happen to be *two* programming languages called Swift: [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(parallel_scripting_language)).

Comment: OK. I got confused cause Apple link [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) to the other language. I was sure it is a reference to the official language website. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the one in your link, use trace() instead of println(). As Matt said, this is another 'Swift', not the one used by Apple.

trace() document: 
http://swift-lang.org/guides/release-0.94/userguide/userguide.html#_trace

```
**9.3. trace**
trace will log its parameters. By default these will appear on both stdout and in the run log file. Some formatting occurs to produce the log message. The particular output format should not be relied upon. (since Swift 0.4)
```

Example:

```
trace("Hello world!!!")
```

You can also use this simulator to test swift
http://swift-lang.org/tryswift/

Comment: Yes, I saw these comments after had posted my post. I don't know if I should delete the post or not.